Missing Solana tokens after staking on crypto.com defi wallet
The tokens no longer show up on my defi wallet.
The wallet address is - Gf61u6gM7KRavWMqLuGuJqKmiQy3qcsertMBgT7e3muD
The smart contract is and transaction ID' are -
gm89b9Aoa472MVpGcBFVAjodFvAWTPxh2m5FW3Np3isNgZNL8fJXVVoWWjXCKnXghEUrUhsTThTo7M17Q6EtaSQ
DdCNGDpP7qMgoAy6paFzhhak2EeyCZcgjH7ak5u5v28m

I can see the 43.5 SOL on stake account.
Stake account: https://solscan.io/account/Gf61u6gM7KRavWMqLuGuJqKmiQy3qcsertMBgT7e3muD
Your Wallet: https://solscan.io/account/7GAtZa3wnyUwSwzzPhFTr5g9rgUNhcE87dXP48Sf3nPq

